# Hiding specific element in CSS when different element is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, woocommerce

I'm not sure is there any way to do this.

I put this into my **CSS** style:

```
.prdctfltr_filter.prdctfltr_attributes.prdctfltr_cat.pf_attr_text.prdctfltr_multi.prdctfltr_adoptive.prdctfltr_merge_terms {display:none}
```

And it's working but what I need is to hide it only when this shows up on my page ->

```
<label class=" prdctfltr_active prdctfltr_ft_girls">
    <input type="checkbox" value="girls" checked=""><span>Clothes for girls (3)</span>
</label>
```

Any script or something to achive that?

Best Regards

Comment: So how this `label` is shown or hidden?  Following user interaction or what? Or do you mean this label can exist or not on page? You should really improve your question with more info and maybe a CSS only solution could be possible, depending what you formely mean and HTML markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jquery to check for the element on the page and hide it if exists

Example

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(.prdctfltr_ft_girls).length){

       $(".prdctfltr_filter.prdctfltr_attributes.prdctfltr_cat.pf_attr_text.prdctfltr_multi.prdctfltr_adoptive.prdctfltr_merge_terms").hide();

    }
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: what about using the `visible` selector?

Answer (score 0):

A CSS solution is possible if and only if you want to show/hide a descendant of the tag which appears or does not appear. Example:

```
.my-inner-item {
    /*Some styling*/
}

.my-outer-item .my-inner-item {
    display: none;
}
```

If this does not match your situation, then this is unsolvable with CSS, since there is no possibility in CSS to set non-descendant different tags. As a result, you need a Javascript solution, possibly with a library, like jQuery or AngularJS. Do not worry, this is well-documented, so googling will more than less solve your problem.